# CakePHP 2.x Auth Custom Username (Code in place but not working!)

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Sorry - Hate to ask but I've spent hour's working this out and researching but havent had any luck.

CakePHP (running the latest version) seems to refuse to use the fields setting (So that I can use the email column in the database as the username). If I set it to 'email' which is the field I wish to use from the database it simply refuses to login stating incorrect details. Cant get any output from SQL in DebugKit for some reason. Although when it's set to username as per below it works fine just using a 'temp' column in the DB. I've tried putting it in the components var but had no luck with that either. What could I be doing wrong? Debug is on, cant see any errors in the log or browser.

The model does contain an email column.

**Controller/AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

        public $components = array(
                'Session',
                'DebugKit.Toolbar',
                'Auth' => array(
                        'allow' => array('login','logout'),
                        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'),
                        'authorize' => 'Controller'
                )
        );

        function beforeFilter() {
                Security::setHash('md5');
                $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                        'Form' => array(
                                'fields' => array(
                                        'username' => 'username',
                                ),
                        ),
                );
        }
}
```

**Controller/UserController.php**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

        public $uses = array('User');

        public function beforeFilter() {
                parent::beforeFilter();
        }

        public function isAuthorized($user){
                return true;
        }

        public function login() {
                $this->layout = 'login';

                if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                        } else {
                                $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, try again','flash_error');
                        }
                }
        }

        public function logout() {
                $this->layout = 'login';

                $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully logged out!','flash_success');
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }

}
```

**View/Users/login.ctp**

```
<?php
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Login');

        echo $this->Session->flash();
        echo $this->Session->flash('auth','flash_info');

        echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
                'action' => 'login'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('username',array(
                'between' => '<br/>',
                'before' => '<p>',
                'after' => '</p>',
                'class' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Email:'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('password',array(
                'between' => '<br/>',
                'before' => '<p>',
                'after' => '</p>',
                'class' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Password:'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->submit('Login', array(
                'class' => 'submit',
                'before' => '<p>',
                'after' => '</p>'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of the field on your form from username to email. Just setting the label to "email" is not enough.

```
        echo $this->Form->input('email',array(
            'between' => '<br/>',
            'before' => '<p>',
            'after' => '</p>',
            'class' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Email:'
```

Comment: Could have sworn I'd tried that... Must have been in combination with something else causing it to have not worked originally.

All works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the components code in your appController to add the authenticate values to the Auth array like this:

```
public $components = array(
            'Session',
            'DebugKit.Toolbar',
            'Auth' => array(
                    'allow' => array('login','logout'),
                    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
                    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index'),
                    'authorize' => 'Controller',
                    'authenticate' => array(
                        'Form' => array(
                                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
                            )
                    )
            )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bill.

Unfortunatly I'd tried that one already and It has the same affect as the above code. I just tried again simply copying the authenticate array from the above code to ensure it wasnt my spelling but still no luck!

I'd happily attempt to debug... But I cant find any logs to debug from :(